# I need to display a spinner on each row of custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

The idea is I want to display list of mp3 files from SDCARD in listview, each line is also contain a spinner with three items (share, rename and delete), I used custom arrayadapter for this purpose and I am stuck on how to add the spinner on the custom arrayadapter class

this is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="416dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="Stop" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is where i create the spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="14dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|start"
     />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="31dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/download"
    >
</Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

here I create the datatype

```
public class MyDataType {

// Name of the song
private String mSongName;

// Drawable Menu resource ID
private int mSpinner;

/** Audio resource ID for the word */
//private int mAudioResourceId;

//public MyDataType(String vName, int  imageResourceId, int audioResourceId){
public MyDataType(String vName, int  spinner){
    mSongName = vName;
    mSpinner = spinner;
    //mAudioResourceId = audioResourceId;
}

public String getSongName() {
    return mSongName;
}

public int getSpinner() {
    return mSpinner;
}
}
```

here i create the custom adapter

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataType> {

public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyDataType> words) {
    super(context, 0, words);
}

Spinner mSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mAdapter;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyDataType currentSong = getItem(position);

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.song_list, parent, false);
}

    TextView songTextView = (TextView) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    songTextView.setText(currentSong.getSongName());

    mSpinner = (Spinner) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

this is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String SD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Xylophone/";
ArrayList<MyDataType> file_list = new ArrayList<MyDataType>();
private final ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    //updatePlayList();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        fillList();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }

    final SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, file_list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try{
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),e.getMessage() );
            }

        }
    });

    Button stopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);

    stopPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mp.stop();
        }
    });
}

private void fillList() {
    File file = new File(SD_PATH );
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        //file_list.add(list[i].getName(),);
        songs.add(list[i].getName());
        MyDataType myList = new MyDataType(list[i].getName(), R.id.spinner);
        file_list.add(myList);
    }
}
}
```

the string value that cotain menu items

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">PlayMp3List</string>

<string-array name="spinner_data">
    <item>Rename</item>
    <item>Delete</item>
    <item>Share</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems that you have almost every thing in place that you need.  However, there are a few minor changes you will need to make before this is working.  First, in the code where you check the permissions if permission is granted, you call fillList().  But in the Else condition, you request the permission.  In the code above, you are not showing how you are handling the result of the request for permission.  If the permission is granted after the request, then in that case, you must also call fillList() there as well.  And, after calling fillList() there, you will also need to recreate the SongAdapter, and also redo the setAdapter on your list view.

In fillList(), you are initializing your myList item with the song title, and the ID of a spinner.  You shouldn't be doing that.  What you should be doing is populating the myList item with the 'value' of the spinner... and the default should probably be 0.

In your getView() method in the custom Adapter, you are getting the current item based on the position parameter and putting the song title into the textView.  Then, you are getting a reference to the Spinner, but you are not doing anything with it.  After getting the reference you should be doing something like mSpinner.value = currentSong.getSpinner();

What you want to do in your MyDataType class is to store the value of the spinner, not any reference to the spinner itself.  You also need some sort of click event so that if the user changes the value of the spinner in the row, you can update your ArrayList with the new value.  That assumes the user can change that selected spinner item, if not, then when you are creating the list, you have to figure out what value to set each song's spinner value with, which you are not doing.

Your Adapter code should look like this.  Note the removal of getContext().

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataType> {

    Context mContext = null;

public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyDataType> words) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    mContext = context;
}

Spinner mSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mAdapter;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyDataType currentSong = getItem(position);

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext.inflate(R.layout.song_list, parent, false);
}

    TextView songTextView = (TextView) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    songTextView.setText(currentSong.getSongName());

    mSpinner = (Spinner) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mSpinner.value = currentSong.getSpinner();

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

In your list item click method you will need to set a breakpoint to see that the path you are passing in mp.setDataSource is a valid path.  It is possible that your SD_PATH needs a '/' at the end or something.

In your layout.xml file you would define your spinner like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />
```

Where the entries @array/country_arrays points to the list that you defined in Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MyAndroidApp</string>
    <string name="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

You are missing the value in your spinner xml definition:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="31dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/download"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_data"
    >
</Spinner>
```

Comment: in the third part you are right I could't do anything, i tried with this [code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#java)  badly, but it's need a context, if you see here the first parameter need a context (ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
) but it always show error, I know I have to fill the spinner, this is exactly where i'm stucked

Comment: Yes, their code is a little confusing.  They are using a built-in Adapter class, so, they are passing the ID of the layout for the list item.  But, their naming convention makes it sound like a layout for the spinner, not the list item.  You don't need to pass that because in your getView() method, you are inflating the layout manually.  You are using getContext() which will probably work, but you should declare a local variable Context mContext, and in the Adapter's initialization method say mContext = context (that was passed into the initialization), then mContext.inflate

Comment: I declared a globale variable on the custom adapter,  Context mContext as you said then mContext = getContext(); then mContext.inflate, after that I replace the mContext in the context of this [code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#java) now I have menu displayed on each row but when I click on the file name there is no sound

Comment: there is an error here     `mSpinner.value = currentSong.getSpinner();`
cannot resolve symbol value

Comment: Yes, I haven't used the Spinner class before, so, that was just a guess, but I think the real way to set the selection is using this:  mSpinner.setSelection(currentSong.getSpinner());

Comment: now there is no error but please in my case how i can fill the spinner to display the menu

Comment: OK, I added another section to my answer to show you how.

Comment: thanks for this section, but I already have that, instead of countries I have Rename, delete and share

Comment: You need to add the android:entries line to your Spinner definition xml file. See above.

Comment: Hi Michael, Coool :) now I have a menu on each row but when I click on the mp3 files they are not working, before they are working

Comment: It is possible that the Spinner is intercepting the 'click' event from the listview.  Put a breakpoint in the onItemClick() method to see if it is getting called.  Try that before/after the latest change you made to see if this is what made the difference.

Comment: when I delete the  `android:entries="@array/spinner_data"` the mp3 files working, but the menu is not working

Comment: So, like I said, you have to put a breakpoint inside of the onItemClick() method to verify if onItemClick() gets called when you delete the android:entries line, and that it doesn't get called when you add the android:entries line.  I suspect that is true, but you'll need to prove it first.  If that is the case, you need to post a new question about what to do if your Spinner prevents your ListView onItemClick event from firing.  That's a whole separate question from this one, which was only about displaying the Spinner in the list.